# Suppressing Transient Voltages - DC circuit

Tags: dc, transient-suppression

I have a DC circuit with a 24-26v voltage source (from a battery).

The secondary function of the circuit consists of 2x step down converters, 1x to 5v and 1x to 12v.

The step down converters are connected via an interrupt switch to toggle complete the circuit to them.

In some circuits I've built (I make a lot of these for some projects I make), when either plugging the battery in or switching the toggle on (rocker switch), one or both of the step down converters will burn up and fry, (sometimes there are no issues).

The step down converters are able to handle 26v without issue as per specifications.

Upon inspection, this seems to be an issue of transient voltage spikes effecting the system when energized and rocker switches can "bounce" their contacts which can create much higher transient voltages outside of the spec of the step down units.

The step down units could be changed but my question is can I instead use either a MOV or Zener Diode to suppress the transients? If so, would I simply choose a voltage that I want the transient to be cut off at and what happens when this voltage is reached? Will it effect anything else plugged in (i.e. shorting the system)? This issue only really occurs at power on or toggling the switch. I have also read I can potentially use a high ESR capacitor. Thoughts on any of this would be much appreciated. I want to be able to put about 25 watts max through this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really need to take a look at the inputs using an oscilloscope to see if the issue is that you are exceeding the absolute maximum input voltage for the switching converter, or if it is some kind of switching startup issue.

If the problem is high voltage (or high differential voltage caused by ground bounce):

It is possible that adding a relatively high ESR electrolytic capacitor on the input side might help with the inductive spikes on the input.

It is also possible that using input protection (probably a unidirectional TVS diode) will solve the problem.

If the problem is a switching startup issue:

Most switching converters have a slow-start circuit, usually an internal current source that charges an external capacitor.  This is used to limit the startup current required to charge the output capacitors on the switching converter and at the load.  Increasing the value of this capacitor (slowing the startup) can solve these kinds of issues.

Comment: Thanks! the issue is exceeding the maximum input voltage, not switching startup. Is there any benefit to a TVS diode over a high ESR capacitor? Also, it seems easy to locate low a ESR capacitor. I suppose just a standard "non solid" capacitor is considered a high ESR type?. If they (TVS vs capacitor) are treated equally (which from the looks of the varying TVS diode choices, they are not, the capacitor approach would be much easier.

Comment: The TVS diodes have a limited ability to absorb energy (although they are pretty impressive in this regard).  The issue is the margin between the operating voltage and the required clamp voltage.  You need a bit of a difference between the two to use a TVS.  A zener can operate with a lower margin between the two but their power handling capability is typically much lower and they will be more costly.  Pretty much any electrolytic cap will work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put a large electrolytic capacitor and a film capacitor across your power rails before the power supply(ies) but AFTER the switch. This will handle the switch bounce and long duration (10's to 100's of milliseconds) transients. The TVS isn't a bad idea either, however, they-re designed for suppressing very high (100's to a few kV's) and very short (microsecond) voltage transients.

Depending on your setup, you could probably use one electrolytic that's common to all your convertors and a film cap local to each one of them.